# Source for medrash that Klal Yisroel counted the omer when they came out of Mitzraim

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, sefirat-ha-omer, dor-hamidbar

The sefer Tur Bareket ([OC 489](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44445&st=&pgnum=173), also brought [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_22462_148.pdf)) quotes a medrash that Moshe Rabbeinu told Klal Yisroel to count 50 days towards matan torah.
Do any of our readers know the exact source in the medrash of his quotation?